# nvidia-driver-515 throws error on kernel 5.15 inside Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, nvidia

I am trying to install CUDA 11.7 on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. Based on [the official documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/11.7.1/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html), kernel 5.15 is supported for Ubuntu 22.04. However, when I tried installing cuda, the installer throws the following error:

```
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/nvidia-kernel-source-515.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.5.0-18-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/515.65.01/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-dkms-515 (--configure):
 installed nvidia-dkms-515 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Setting up nsight-systems-2022.1.3 (2022.1.3.3-1c7b5f7) ...
update-alternatives: using /opt/nvidia/nsight-systems/2022.1.3/target-linux-x64/nsys to provide /usr/local/bin/nsys (nsys) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /opt/nvidia/nsight-systems/2022.1.3/host-linux-x64/nsys-ui to provide /usr/local/bin/nsys-ui (nsys-ui) in auto mode
Setting up libxml2:i386 (2.9.13+dfsg-1ubuntu0.3) ...
Setting up libcufile-dev-11-7 (1.3.1.18-1) ...
Setting up cuda-libraries-11-7 (11.7.1-1) ...
Setting up libxcb-dri3-0:i386 (1.14-3ubuntu3) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda-drivers-515:
 cuda-drivers-515 depends on nvidia-dkms-515 (>= 515.65.01); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-515 is not configured yet.
```

I found the following error inside log files:

```
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/515.65.01/build/common/inc/nv-mm.h: In function ‘NV_GET_USER_PAGES_REMOTE’:
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/515.65.01/build/common/inc/nv-mm.h:164:45: error: passing argument 1 of ‘get_user_pages_remote’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  164 |                return get_user_pages_remote(tsk, mm, start, nr_pages, flags,
      |                                             ^~~
      |                                             |
      |                                             struct task_struct *
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/515.65.01/build/common/inc/nv-pgprot.h:30,
```

The error is generated during the installation of NVIDIA driver 515. Though documentation says installing it, it seems that **NVIDIA driver 515 is incompatible with kernel 5.15 inside Ubuntu 22.04**. Similarly, I tried installing the NVIDIA Open GPU Kernel Modules package by `sudo apt install -y nvidia-kernel-open-515`, but it throws a similar error.

##### NVIDIA Driver 535

Later on, I installed NVIDIA driver based on [this suggesiton](https://askubuntu.com/a/1258909/) using the following command:

```
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers install
```

The above command installed `nvidia-driver-535 (535.154.05-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)`. Then, I installed `cuda-toolkit-11-7` package (notice, it is not `cuda-11-7` package). Finally, I am supposed to install `cuda-driver-535` but there is no such package as shown below:

```
$ sudo apt install cuda-driver
cuda-driver-dev-11-7            cuda-drivers-fabricmanager-450  cuda-drivers-fabricmanager-515
cuda-drivers                    cuda-drivers-fabricmanager-460  cuda-drivers-fabricmanager-525
cuda-drivers-515                cuda-drivers-fabricmanager-470  cuda-drivers-fabricmanager-535
cuda-drivers-fabricmanager      cuda-drivers-fabricmanager-510
```

To check my faith, I installed `cuda-drivers-515` but it removed `nvidia-driver-535` as shown below:

```
$ sudo apt install cuda-drivers-515
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libnvidia-cfg1-535 libnvidia-common-535 libnvidia-compute-535 libnvidia-compute-535:i386 libnvidia-decode-535
  libnvidia-decode-535:i386 libnvidia-encode-535 libnvidia-encode-535:i386 libnvidia-extra-535 libnvidia-fbc1-535
  libnvidia-fbc1-535:i386 libnvidia-gl-535 libnvidia-gl-535:i386 linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.5.0-18-generic
  linux-modules-nvidia-535-generic-hwe-22.04 nvidia-compute-utils-535 nvidia-driver-535 nvidia-kernel-common-535
  nvidia-kernel-source-535 nvidia-utils-535 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-535
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cuda-drivers-515 dctrl-tools dkms libegl-mesa0:i386 libegl1:i386 libgbm1:i386 libgles2:i386 libnvidia-cfg1-515
  libnvidia-common-515 libnvidia-compute-515 libnvidia-compute-515:i386 libnvidia-decode-515 libnvidia-decode-515:i386
  libnvidia-encode-515 libnvidia-encode-515:i386 libnvidia-extra-515 libnvidia-fbc1-515 libnvidia-fbc1-515:i386
  libnvidia-gl-515 libnvidia-gl-515:i386 libopengl0:i386 libwayland-client0:i386 libwayland-server0:i386
  nvidia-compute-utils-515 nvidia-dkms-515 nvidia-driver-515 nvidia-kernel-common-515 nvidia-kernel-source-515
  nvidia-modprobe nvidia-utils-515 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515
0 upgraded, 31 newly installed, 21 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
```

But the problem persists.

##### Kernel 6.2

As this point, I thought how about using a newer kernel (though it is not mentioned in the official documentation). So I used `6.2.0-39-generic`. However, the similar error was reported.

**Which nvidia driver is the recommened for CUDA 11.7 in Ubuntu 22.04?**

##### Update

###### Env Info:

```
$ uname -a
Linux asus 5.15.0-94-generic #104-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 9 15:25:40 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ ldd --version
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.35-0ubuntu3.6) 2.35
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

###### Installation Steps

```
$ sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-11-7-local_11.7.1-515.65.01-1_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-11-7-local.
(Reading database ... 777187 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-11-7-local_11.7.1-515.65.01-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-11-7-local (11.7.1-515.65.01-1) ...
Setting up cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-11-7-local (11.7.1-515.65.01-1) ...

The public CUDA GPG key does not appear to be installed.
To install the key, run this command:
sudo cp /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-11-7-local/cuda-F83D2C4C-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/

$ sudo cp /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-11-7-local/cuda-F83D2C4C-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/

$ sudo apt update

$ sudo apt install cuda-11-7 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  cuda-cccl-11-7 cuda-command-line-tools-11-7 cuda-compiler-11-7 cuda-cudart-11-7 cuda-cudart-dev-11-7
  cuda-cuobjdump-11-7 cuda-cupti-11-7 cuda-cupti-dev-11-7 cuda-cuxxfilt-11-7 cuda-demo-suite-11-7
  cuda-documentation-11-7 cuda-driver-dev-11-7 cuda-drivers cuda-drivers-515 cuda-gdb-11-7 cuda-libraries-11-7
  cuda-libraries-dev-11-7 cuda-memcheck-11-7 cuda-nsight-11-7 cuda-nsight-compute-11-7 cuda-nsight-systems-11-7
  cuda-nvcc-11-7 cuda-nvdisasm-11-7 cuda-nvml-dev-11-7 cuda-nvprof-11-7 cuda-nvprune-11-7 cuda-nvrtc-11-7
  cuda-nvrtc-dev-11-7 cuda-nvtx-11-7 cuda-nvvp-11-7 cuda-runtime-11-7 cuda-sanitizer-11-7 cuda-toolkit-11-7
  cuda-toolkit-11-7-config-common cuda-toolkit-11-config-common cuda-toolkit-config-common cuda-tools-11-7
  cuda-visual-tools-11-7 dctrl-tools dkms gds-tools-11-7 libatomic1:i386 libbsd0:i386 libcublas-11-7
  libcublas-dev-11-7 libcufft-11-7 libcufft-dev-11-7 libcufile-11-7 libcufile-dev-11-7 libcurand-11-7
  libcurand-dev-11-7 libcusolver-11-7 libcusolver-dev-11-7 libcusparse-11-7 libcusparse-dev-11-7 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386
  libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libedit2:i386 libegl-mesa0:i386
  libegl1:i386 libelf1:i386 libexpat1:i386 libffi8:i386 libgbm1:i386 libgl1:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
  libglapi-mesa:i386 libgles2:i386 libglvnd0:i386 libglx-mesa0:i386 libglx0:i386 libicu70:i386 libllvm15:i386
  libmd0:i386 libnpp-11-7 libnpp-dev-11-7 libnvidia-cfg1-515 libnvidia-common-515 libnvidia-compute-515
  libnvidia-compute-515:i386 libnvidia-decode-515 libnvidia-decode-515:i386 libnvidia-encode-515
  libnvidia-encode-515:i386 libnvidia-extra-515 libnvidia-fbc1-515 libnvidia-fbc1-515:i386 libnvidia-gl-515
  libnvidia-gl-515:i386 libnvjpeg-11-7 libnvjpeg-dev-11-7 libopengl0:i386 libpciaccess0:i386 libsensors5:i386
  libstdc++6:i386 libtinfo5 libwayland-client0:i386 libwayland-server0:i386 libx11-6:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386
  libxau6:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-randr0:i386
  libxcb-shm0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb-xfixes0:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386
  libxml2:i386 libxshmfence1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 nsight-compute-2022.2.1 nsight-systems-2022.1.3
  nvidia-compute-utils-515 nvidia-dkms-515 nvidia-driver-515 nvidia-kernel-common-515 nvidia-kernel-source-515
  nvidia-modprobe nvidia-prime nvidia-settings nvidia-utils-515 screen-resolution-extra xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515
Suggested packages:
  debtags menu lm-sensors:i386
Recommended packages:
  libgl1-amber-dri:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cuda-11-7 cuda-cccl-11-7 cuda-command-line-tools-11-7 cuda-compiler-11-7 cuda-cudart-11-7 cuda-cudart-dev-11-7
  cuda-cuobjdump-11-7 cuda-cupti-11-7 cuda-cupti-dev-11-7 cuda-cuxxfilt-11-7 cuda-demo-suite-11-7
  cuda-documentation-11-7 cuda-driver-dev-11-7 cuda-drivers cuda-drivers-515 cuda-gdb-11-7 cuda-libraries-11-7
  cuda-libraries-dev-11-7 cuda-memcheck-11-7 cuda-nsight-11-7 cuda-nsight-compute-11-7 cuda-nsight-systems-11-7
  cuda-nvcc-11-7 cuda-nvdisasm-11-7 cuda-nvml-dev-11-7 cuda-nvprof-11-7 cuda-nvprune-11-7 cuda-nvrtc-11-7
  cuda-nvrtc-dev-11-7 cuda-nvtx-11-7 cuda-nvvp-11-7 cuda-runtime-11-7 cuda-sanitizer-11-7 cuda-toolkit-11-7
  cuda-toolkit-11-7-config-common cuda-toolkit-11-config-common cuda-toolkit-config-common cuda-tools-11-7
  cuda-visual-tools-11-7 dctrl-tools dkms gds-tools-11-7 libatomic1:i386 libbsd0:i386 libcublas-11-7
  libcublas-dev-11-7 libcufft-11-7 libcufft-dev-11-7 libcufile-11-7 libcufile-dev-11-7 libcurand-11-7
  libcurand-dev-11-7 libcusolver-11-7 libcusolver-dev-11-7 libcusparse-11-7 libcusparse-dev-11-7 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386
  libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libedit2:i386 libegl-mesa0:i386
  libegl1:i386 libelf1:i386 libexpat1:i386 libffi8:i386 libgbm1:i386 libgl1:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
  libglapi-mesa:i386 libgles2:i386 libglvnd0:i386 libglx-mesa0:i386 libglx0:i386 libicu70:i386 libllvm15:i386
  libmd0:i386 libnpp-11-7 libnpp-dev-11-7 libnvidia-cfg1-515 libnvidia-common-515 libnvidia-compute-515
  libnvidia-compute-515:i386 libnvidia-decode-515 libnvidia-decode-515:i386 libnvidia-encode-515
  libnvidia-encode-515:i386 libnvidia-extra-515 libnvidia-fbc1-515 libnvidia-fbc1-515:i386 libnvidia-gl-515
  libnvidia-gl-515:i386 libnvjpeg-11-7 libnvjpeg-dev-11-7 libopengl0:i386 libpciaccess0:i386 libsensors5:i386
  libstdc++6:i386 libtinfo5 libwayland-client0:i386 libwayland-server0:i386 libx11-6:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386
  libxau6:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-randr0:i386
  libxcb-shm0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb-xfixes0:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386
  libxml2:i386 libxshmfence1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 nsight-compute-2022.2.1 nsight-systems-2022.1.3
  nvidia-compute-utils-515 nvidia-dkms-515 nvidia-driver-515 nvidia-kernel-common-515 nvidia-kernel-source-515
  nvidia-modprobe nvidia-prime nvidia-settings nvidia-utils-515 screen-resolution-extra xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-515
0 upgraded, 133 newly installed, 0 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/2,668 MB of archives.
After this operation, 6,272 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
...
...
...
A new initrd image has also been created. To revert, please regenerate your
initrd by running the following command after deleting the modprobe.d file:
`/usr/sbin/initramfs -u`

*****************************************************************************
*** Reboot your computer and verify that the NVIDIA graphics driver can   ***
*** be loaded.                                                            ***
*****************************************************************************

INFO:Enable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
Loading new nvidia-515.65.01 DKMS files...
Building for 5.15.0-94-generic 6.5.0-18-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.15.0-94-generic
Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
Done.

nvidia.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.15.0-94-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-modeset.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.15.0-94-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-drm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.15.0-94-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-peermem.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.15.0-94-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-uvm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.15.0-94-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod...
Building initial module for 6.5.0-18-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/nvidia-kernel-source-515.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.5.0-18-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/515.65.01/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-dkms-515 (--configure):
 installed nvidia-dkms-515 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Setting up nsight-systems-2022.1.3 (2022.1.3.3-1c7b5f7) ...
update-alternatives: using /opt/nvidia/nsight-systems/2022.1.3/target-linux-x64/nsys to provide /usr/local/bin/nsys (nsy
s) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /opt/nvidia/nsight-systems/2022.1.3/host-linux-x64/nsys-ui to provide /usr/local/bin/nsys-ui 
(nsys-ui) in auto mode
Setting up libxml2:i386 (2.9.13+dfsg-1ubuntu0.3) ...
Setting up libcufile-dev-11-7 (1.3.1.18-1) ...
Setting up cuda-libraries-11-7 (11.7.1-1) ...
Setting up libxcb-dri3-0:i386 (1.14-3ubuntu3) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda-drivers-515:
 cuda-drivers-515 depends on nvidia-dkms-515 (>= 515.65.01); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-515 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-drivers-515 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libx11-xcb1:i386 (2:1.7.5-1ubuntu0.3) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Setting up lib
gbm1:i386 (23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2) ...
Setting up cuda-compiler-11-7 (11.7.1-1) ...
Setting up cuda-cupti-11-7 (11.7.101-1) ...
Setting up libxext6:i386 (2:1.3.4-1build1) ...
Setting up cuda-cupti-dev-11-7 (11.7.101-1) ...
Setting up libxxf86vm1:i386 (1:1.1.4-1build3) ...
Setting up libegl-mesa0:i386 (23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2) ...
Setting up libxfixes3:i386 (1:6.0.0-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda-drivers:
 cuda-drivers depends on cuda-drivers-515 (= 515.65.01-1); however:
  Package cuda-drivers-515 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-drivers (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependen
cy problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver-515:
 nvidia-driver-515 depends on nvidia-dkms-515 (= 515.65.01-0ubuntu1); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-515 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-515 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up libnvidia-decode-515:i386 (515.65.01-0ubuntu1) 
...
Setting up libllvm15:i386 (1:15.0.7-0ubuntu0.22.04.3) ...
Setting up libegl1:i386 (1.4.0-1) ...
Setting up cuda-nsight-systems-11-7 (11.7.1-1) ...
Setting up cuda-libraries-dev-11-7 (11.7.1-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda-runtime-11-7:
 cuda-runtime-11-7 depends on cuda-drivers (>= 515.65.01); however:
  Package cuda-drivers is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-runtime-11-7 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2) ...
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Setting up cuda-command-line-tools-11-7 (11.7.1-1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-encode-515:i386 (515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up cuda-visual-tools-11-7 (11.7.1-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda-demo-suite-11-7:
 cuda-demo-suite-11-7 depends on cuda-runtime-11-7; however:
  Package cuda-runtime-11-7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-demo-suite-11-7 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cuda-11-7:
 cuda-11-7 depends on cuda-runtime-11-7 (>= 11.7.1); however:
  Package cuda-runtime-11-7 is not configured yet.
 cuda-11-7 depends on cuda-demo-suite-11-7 (>= 11.7.91); however:
  Package cuda-demo-suite-11-7 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cuda-11-7 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libglx-mesa0:i386 (23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2) ...
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached alr
eady
    Setting up libglx0:i386 (1.4.0-1) ...
Setting up libgl1:i386 (1.4.0-1) ...
Setting up cuda-tools-11-7 (11.7.1-1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-gl-515:i386 (515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libnvidia-fbc1-515:i386 (515.65.01-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up cuda-toolkit-11-7 (11.7.1-1) ...
Setting alternatives
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.6+22.04.20220217-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.6) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.20-2ubuntu4.1) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-18-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-dkms-515
 cuda-drivers-515
 cuda-drivers
 nvidia-driver-515
 cuda-runtime-11-7
 cuda-demo-suite-11-7
 cuda-11-7
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

###### Log Files

Since [crash file](https://pastebin.com/0Ypk9dwg) and [log file](https://pastebin.com/ScpiSNTL) are really large, I uploaded them to Pastebin.

Comment: `Bad return status for module build on kernel:`  **`6.5.0-18-generic`**  `(x86_64)` versus **`kernel 5.15`** `inside Ubuntu 22.04`: there's a discrepancy in what you tell.

Comment: @A.B: Thank you very much. Just now, I added the update section, please have a look.

Comment: No need to look at everything. Remove the part that makes it not work and try again: remove any reference (package or local install) about kernel 6.5.

Comment: The OS has multiple kernels, such as 6.5. However, the current (logged-in session) kernel is 5.15. I can not uninstall kernel 6.5, but is there any way to stop Nvidia-driver from compiling for 6.5?

Comment: I pointed you to the reason (that you missed) you have this error: kernel 6.5 and not 5.15 (as in the title). Now it's up to you or someone else to choose to fix it or not. You should amend your question to state what is your new goal: is it still "which nvidia driver?", is it how to compile nvidia driver in presence of non-supported kernel headers? Something else?

Comment: Thank you very much. If I understood you correctly, the error is coming due to kernel 6.5. However, removing the latest kernel does not seem to be a fix. Moreover, my goal is to install CUDA 11.7 on Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: kerneltree 6.5 is the newest kernel for hw-stack. But you have also linux-image-generic on your system with 5.15 kerneltree. So you can remove the hw stack. Both kernel are the newest for his own kerneltree. And when I look to devnvidia repo it should also be a package that fits your nvidia version.  `sudo apt update` please [edit] your question for output and `dkms status` also. Thanks.